# Java program for changing the directory of command prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have written a java program named Automate.java, in which the another java program named newsmail will be executed.

The problem i face here is, Automate.java is in Desktop location(should be in desktop only always due to some requirements) and newsmail is in `/home/Admin/GATE521/LN_RB` this location.

What must be done before the below code, such that the command prompt automatically goes to the required folder and executes the program.

```
String command = "java newsmail";
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Comment: You could try putting "/home/Admin/GATE521/LN_RB" on your classpath. But I get the feeling that this whole approach is very odd and unusual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this `exec()` :

```
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, new File("/home/Admin/GATE521/LN_RB"));
```

---

**Resources :**

- [javadoc - Runtime.exec()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File))

Comment: command must be the called executable and the second parameter is the list of parameters passed to your command. (@see the link)

Answer (score 3):

Use the new [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, instead of `Runtime.exec()`.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "newsmail");
pb.directory("/home/Admin/GATE521/LN_RB");
pb.start();
```

You can even look at `pb.environment()` to change environment variables if necessary.